# Is it possible to achieve an Icon that represents the number of notifications a user has in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just wanted to ask if anyone here has implemented a notification module for their flutter applications similar to how the twitter notifications work. Wherein there is the icon and the number of notifications a user has is stacked on top of the icon, something kind of like this:

[image: Twitter DM notification]

If possible, How did you implement this? Thanks in advance to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one of the many packages that are available.
e.g. https://pub.dev/packages/badges

Comment: Woah, I was looking for a package like this just a while ago. I didn't see this one, maybe I was searching wrong! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this could help,

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    icon: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
        ),
        new Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.brightness_1,
                size: 15.0,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
              Text(
                '2',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 8.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), onPressed: () {
                  }),
                  new Positioned(
                    right: 11,
                    top: 11,
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      ),
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        minWidth: 15,
                        minHeight: 15,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        '$notificationsCount',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 10,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],)
```

This shows the notification count with notification icon

update the Notifications Count

```
setState(() {
  notificationsCount = "5";
});
```